# Expected eigenvalues of Gram matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, expectation, random-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $x \in R^p $ is drawn from some distribution $p(x)$ and $ A \in R^{N \times N} $ is gram matrix formed by dot product of $x_i, x_j$. What are the expected eigenvalues of $A$ when $N$ is finite?